# Google-Play-Services Lib Project - Gone Today After SDK Update

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I am working on an a small legacy Android application which was developed in Eclipse. The application has a Google Map in it which up until this morning was working fine.

I got a new Nexus P6 and decided to update the nexus drivers via the SDK manager. With it was also updates to new Android versions and the Build Tools. 
It broke my project. More specifically it actually broke the Google-Play-Services lib project which is now missing from my Android SDK installation.

Going to the following directory:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services

I get

- docs/
- samples/
- source.properties

But no lib project. The Froyo lib project is still there. Also, the SDK manager shows Google Play Services is installed.  I tried uninstalling it then re-installing it but the lib project will not come back.

Does anyone have any advice on how I can fix this odd issue?

[edit]
The current and previous versions of the Google play Services are given below:

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_8487000_r29.zip

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_9080000_r30.zip

It seems r29 contains the lib, but r30 (the most recent) does not. Why has Google done that!?

I copied the lib project from r29 to the place where is should normally exist within the SDK and imported the Google-Play-Services lib project in the usual way.  However, it's not playing ball the projct is unable to find appcompat v7 even when I manually reference either the Jar for this comparability library or import the project as a dependency of the Google-Play-Services lib.

Comment: IMHO, these questions need more visibility (all of them). And there is no answer in the other question, as to why Google did it?

Comment: I'd really like to post how managed to overcome this problem but I cannot because it is marked as duplicate.

Comment: I'd like to tell you to. However, I did provide a good answer elsewhere to this problem once I discovered the other question.